# How to create an EngineYard-like service for other languages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting, web-hosting

Does anyone know what is needed to create an EngineYard-like service for other languages? Where should one start?

Thanks

Comment: As it stands, no one who it not familiar with the EngineYard of which you speak, will be bale to help you, and you haven't even provided a link. Not that a link is really enough: give a short description of what it does as well to maximize your potential audience. // Not that this is a pet peeve of mine, or anything. Sheesh.

Answer (score 3):

Umpteen million dollars in (VC) capital and a large team of dedicated developers and sysadmins always helps.

If you don't really want to emulate Engine Yard in all its glory, but just want some more automated deployment options, you might want to ask more directed questions which mention which language(s) you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

You just need

- EC2 where you have your server
- Chef to create some cookbook
- Write the code.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I think you're over simplifying. "write the code", what code? Not the app code I imagine.  thanks

Comment: Yeah, *shingara's* the one over simplifying.  Riiiiight.

Comment: aha, that's brilliant! I'll start right away writing the code ^^